# what is a safe way to plane a cross-grain board?

Tags: thickness-planer

I know that your not supposed to cut cross grain when it comes to planing the wood. But when I am in such a spot what is a good way to do this? The easiest would be to take shallow cuts, as told in a previous question. But what are thing that can be done to be on the safe side. Just to prevent the chip out and all would be nice. Edit: This is done with a 13" thickness planer.

Comment: Do you have a particular size of workpiece in mind?

Comment: With a hand plane, of course, you have more control over direction than with a machine. In particularly complicated grain, changing the angle of the cutting face or switching to a scraper may be worth considering. Or even sanding... And of course some cuts *are* taken across the grain, eg when using a shoulder plane to trim a tenion to fit. Rather than assuming a particular tool, how about telling us what you are trying to do and ash how it can be done?

Comment: There are techniques to add support boards to the wood being planed (sacrificial pieces) but as I commented before, I'm not sure this is even safe to do in a thicknesser because if you get a spelching from the rear edge the flakes could go up into the machine and cause damage. And don't think 'damage' means a boo-boo where you just scrape some paint off a surface. Even if some dude on YouTube can do it repeatably without mishap think about it this way, can *you* afford to replace it if the thicknesser gets ruined by one mistake?

Comment: Now that aside, when would you ever need to? Boards have grain running down their length, if it's safer and gives better results to run them through in that orientation why would you want to try it at 90°??

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate There is no particular size in mind, that is if I where to ever do a cross-grain plane job. I was asking with more in the when-ever it comes to being my only option. Otherwise like graphus said, it is not worth the chances.

Comment: the question is not clear about whether or not this is by machine or by hand. Planing cross grain by machine is a terrible idea for reasons listed above. BY hand it is a wonderful way to get close to finish thickness, since it's a lot easier to do (presuming using a cambered blade as in a fore/scrub plane). In this case, to prevent spelching on the far side, first create a bevel on the side of the board going with the grain. The spelching will be limited to the upper surface of the bevel, but it will not protrude past the actual edge of the board.

Comment: @aaron Oh, did not realize that, I will make a quick edit on what it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For parts too wide for your planer, there are a couple different options. If you have a router, you can make a router sled, and use the router to surface the wood. I believe you will find this process spelled out in other posts on here if you do a quick search.

Depending on how much material you need to take off, you could run it through a drum sander, or do the hand tool route and you a hand plane.

Either way, you do not want to send parts through a planer cross grain. It is unsafe, bad for the tool, and will not produce a satisfying product in most cases.
[image]

Comment: I built a router sled once, but that bottom or top did some kind of warp and messed everything up. But for a while it worked fine. But what is a good way of keeping the work piece in place. I would put 4 boards around and screw. But at times that piece was smaller and it can be a small pain.

Comment: You could do that, or you could use double sided tape. If the backside of the piece is not flat, you may need to shim it in place so that it doesn't move or rock while you are flattening.